# MongoDB Merge Equivalent Collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have two collections with same structure and want to merge them in aggregation result and query & sort over them after merging.

E.g.;

**First collection:**

```
{_id: "123", "name": "sercan"}
```

**Second collection:**

```
{_id: "456", "name": "hakan"}
```

**What I want;**

```
[{_id: "123", "name": "sercan"}, {_id: "456", "name": "hakan"}]
```

**What I tried**;

```
{"from":"secondCollection",pipeline: [],"as":"seconds"}
// result
{_id: "123", "name": "sercan", seconds: [{_id: "456", "name": "hakan"}]}
```

And the above trial, puts all documents into **seconds** if there're more documents in the second collection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Are you looking for a mongo query? Or can you solve this on an application level. I was about to welcome you to SO based on your the fact your question didn't have any code but realised you have quite a bit of rep already :)

Comment: As I already mentioned in the question, I need an aggregation query, let's assume I have millions of documents in both collections, would you still merge them in code side ?

Comment: Added my trial.

Comment: @SercanOzdemir For millions of documents, the lookup cannot be performed as the lookup output would come inside an array and that would exceed the 16MB document size limit of Mongo.

Comment: One approach can be to create a temporary collection say X with initially all the documents of both collections. Later on, a periodic job can be run to insert newly added documents of both collections inside X. Then you would need to execute the query on X only.

Answer (score 0):

The one option I have used is `$merge` in MongoDB.
It's basically merge one collection to another and create new output collection if it does not exist.

Reference:

- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/